# vs2017 cannot browse online extensions

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I just installed Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, and the first thing I do is try and install the extensions I usually prefer.

I open up the Extensions and Updates dialog, which loads all the installed plugins that came with the install.

I click the "Online" tab on the left, and it loads... "No items found". No extensions exist online, huh? I'm sure that's right. `</sarcasm>`

So I try searching. Then I am presented with an error in the Extensions and Updates dialog:

> A connection to the server could not be established because the following error(s) occurred:
>
> The magic number in the GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.
>
> Please click here to retry the request.

I am on a corporate network, so a firewall thing could be a problem, except I would expect that VS2015 would have the same problem, then, which it doesn't. I can browse online extensions in 2015 without any problems.

This is a completely fresh install.

I haven't been able to find anything about this online, every time I find something referencing this error it's because someone is coding something wrong, not because VS is being weird.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just as a side note: I have contacted support, but I'm posting my question here both for posterity and on the off-chance that someone knows how to work around this. If I get an answer from support, I'll put it here in the event no-one else answers the question.

Comment: I have this problem too after doing the 15.3 update on VS2017. It was working before I did that.

Comment: adding another confirmation that this error appeared after the 15.3 update for me.

Comment: For the record, in the Visual Studio Community post I also made, Alex Eyler [MSFT] claimed a fix would be coming to 15.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug that was supposedly fixed in version 15.4.

I can vouch personally for it working fine in version 15.5.1+.

Here's [The Visual Studio Developer Community Problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/94689/vs2017-cannot-browse-online-extensions-incorrect-g.html) I cross-posted that has more details from the MS team. You can see that the accepted solution over there was posted on October 9, stating that it was fixed in 15.4.

Here's also the [Release Notes from Vs2017 v15.4](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.4) for more details about that.